# RODBC Teradata Copy Table

Tags: r, teradata, rodbc

I am using RODBC with R to connect to Teradata.

I am trying to copy a large table `EXAMPLE` (25GB) from the `READ_ONLY` database to the `WORK`database. The two databases are under the same DB system so I only need one connection.

I have tried `sqlQuery`, `sqlCopy` and `sqlCopyTable`functions but do not succeed.

**sqlQuery**

EDIT: syntax error corrected as suggested by @dnoeth.

```
CREATE TABLE WORK.EXAMPLE AS (SELECT * FROM READ_ONLY.EXAMPLE) WITH DATA;
```

OR

```
CREATE TABLE WORK.EXAMPLE AS (SELECT * FROM READ_ONLY.EXAMPLE) WITH NO DATA;
INSERT INTO WORK.EXAMPLE SELECT * FROM READ_ONLY.EXAMPLE;
```

I let the latter method run for 15h but it did not complete the copy.

**sqlCopy**

```
sqlCopy(ch, 
    query='SELECT * FROM READ_ONLY.EXAMPLE',
    destination = 'WORK.EXAMPLE')

Error: cannot allocate vector of size 155.0 Mb
```

Does `sqlCopy` try to first copy the data to R's memory before creating the new table? If so, how can I bypass this step and work exclusively on the Teradata server? Also, the error persists even if use the option `fast=F`.

In case R's memory was the issue, I tried creating a smaller table of 1000 rows:

```
sqlCopy(ch, 
    query='SELECT * FROM READ_ONLY.EXAMPLE SAMPLE 1000',
    destination = 'WORK.EXAMPLE')

Error in sqlSave(destchannel, dataset, destination, verbose = verbose,  : 
  [RODBC] Failed exec in Update
22018 0 [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver] Data is not a numeric-literal.
In addition: Warning message:
In odbcUpdate(channel, query, mydata, coldata[m, ], test = test,  :
  character data '2017-03-20 12:08:25' truncated to 15 bytes in column 'ExtractionTS'
```

With this command a table was actually created but it only includes the column names without any rows.

**sqlCopyTable**

```
sqlCopyTable(ch, 
         srctable = 'READ_ONLY.EXAMPLE',
         desttable = 'WORK.EXAMPLE')

Error in if (as.character(keys[[4L]]) == colnames[i]) create <- paste(create,  : 
  argument is of length zero
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax in your sqlQuery is not correc, the `WITH DATA`option is missing:

```
CREATE TABLE WORK.EXAMPLE AS (SELECT * FROM READ_ONLY.EXAMPLE) WITH DATA;
```

Caution, this will loose all NOT NULL & CHECK constraints and all indexes, resulting in the 1st column as Non-Unique Primary Index.

Either add a PI manually or switch to

```
CREATE TABLE WORK.EXAMPLE AS READ_ONLY.EXAMPLE WITH DATA;
```

if `READ_ONLY.EXAMPLE` is a table and you actually want an exact copy.

Comment: Thank you! The latter suggestion is useful too, but I just learned that I am working with 'views' not 'tables', and the latter command does not work with 'views'. I wonder if sqlCopy and and sqlCopyTable also fail because of this view/table distinction.

Comment: @Maarölli: `sqlCopy` seems to offload data locally and then insert into the new table.